# How to correct float notation within overload function

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, operator-overloading, operators

I am working with a code that is supposed overload with division, power, and float operators. I seem to be having difficulty editing my original code so that the answer is not in float format, but rather integer or string.

The output I keep getting is:

My first rational is 2/7 #correct

Its cube is 8.0/343.0 #incorrect

Its approximate floating point value is 0.2857142857142857 #correct

My second rational is 1/3 #correct

My first rational is 2/2.333333333333333 times larger than the second one #incorrect

The output I should get is:

My first rational is 2/7

Its cube is 8/343

Its approximate floating point value is 0.2857142857142857

My second rational is 1/3

My first rational is 6/7 times larger than the second one

I tried placing str() and int() in front of certain variables in the code but it says those operands do not work for "/" and "**"

When I remove floats from the code, I get this error message:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/Users/******/Desktop/ration/rationaluse.py", line 10, in 
    print("My first rational is", r1/r2, "times larger than the second one")

File "/Users/*****/Desktop/ration/rational.py", line 15, in **truediv**
    return Rational(self.numerator, self.denominator * (other))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'int' and 'Rational

```
'''The file that needs to be edited: '''
from sys import *
class Rational:
    def __init__(self, n, d):
        if d == 0:
            print ("Invalid Denominator!")
        else:
            self.numerator = n
            self.denominator = d
    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.numerator) + "/" + str(self.denominator)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.numerator) + "/" + str(self.denominator)

    def __truediv__(self,other):
        return Rational(self.numerator, self.denominator * float(other))
    def __pow__(self, other):
        return Rational(self.numerator ** float(other), self.denominator ** float(other))
    def __float__(self):
        return self.numerator / self.denominator
```

''' The file that was given to print the output as it is and cannot be edited '''
    from rational import *

```
r1 = Rational(2,7)
print("My first rational is", r1)
print("Its cube is", r1**3)
print("Its approximate floating point value is", float(r1))

r2 = Rational(1,3)
print("My second rational is", r2)
print("My first rational is", r1/r2, "times larger than the second one")
```

Comment: If you don't want your numbers to become floats, what are all the `float(...)` calls doing in your code?

Comment: removing the floats returns errors with operands

Comment: Errors? Like what?